# Android Volley ListView Blinking and Items Remaining

Tags: android, listview, android-volley, handler, runnable

I have a `ListView` with a `CustomAdapter` set to it which displays an array of json objects that I call with a volley request:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,personList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

// Creating volley request obj
     final JsonArrayRequest personReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        person.setfirstName(obj.getString("first_name"));
                        person.setlastName(obj.getString("last_name"));

                        //Add person to list
                        personList.add(person);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                Log.i(TAG, "personList items: " + personList.size());


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        hidePDialog();

    }
});

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(personReq);
```

Using a runnable and handler, I make this request every 5 seconds:

```
    //Run volley request every 5 seconds
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (orderList != null) {
                orderList.clear();
            }

            //Placing here TOO removes the last item but causes blinking
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(personReq);

            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);

        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

The problem is that one item always remains, even though it should not be there (due to removing it via a separate volley request). Tapping the item causes the app to crash with the following from the logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.
```

As you can see, I am calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); directly after adding a person object. It works fine until the last item on the list is gone (but still being seen).

Adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside the Runnable does clear the last item but causes the whole view to blink every 5 seconds.

Is it even possible to prevent this blinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out a way to stop the blinking and clearing the last remaining item.

In addition to the `onResponse` method, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` must also be present in the `onErrorResponse` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your Adapter.

```
public void addAll(List<T> datas) {
    if (datas != null) {
        mData.addAll(datas);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity.

```
personList.add(person);
adapter.addAll(personList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Make sure your adapter calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` when its content changes

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, I am calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); directly
>   after adding a person object.

That's a waste. Call `notifyDataSetChanged` *once*, after the list is in the final state you want to display.

> Adding adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); inside the Runnable does clear
>   the last item but causes the whole view to blink every 5 seconds.
>
> Is it even possible to prevent this blinking?

I can only guess that this "blinking" is because you are clearing the list and refreshing the adapter (thus making the `ListView` empty) before making your network request, which of course will have a delay based on the network condition.

Instead of clearing your list before making your network request, why don't you clear it *after* the response comes back?

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

    personList.clear(); // Wipe the list before adding new data

    // Parsing json
    // The rest of your parsing code here...

    // Now that the list is fully updated to the new state, call this ONCE
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```